# Flask Application Unexpectedly Crashes During User Authentication Process

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, flask

I am working on developing a web application using Python and Flask. When I'm testing the app as a user and I enter my credentials and hit login, the application occasionally crashes, and I get a HTTP 500 Internal Server Error. Here's a censored version of my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user

app = Flask(__name__)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User(user_id)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        # Here would be the code to validate the credentials
        if validate_credentials(username, password):
            user = User(username)
            login_user(user)
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('login.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In my logs I see an error message that says "TypeError: Object of type 'User' is not JSON serializable", but I'm not sure where this issue is coming from.

I think the problem is related to the user session handling, but I'm not sure how to zero in on the problem.

Comment: Your code is so short that it is very difficult to determine where the problem you are describing comes from. Could you at least share the whole traceback ?